# An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Here what I was trying to do

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("retrofit/POST/signup.php")
abstract fun signUp(
    @Field(Constant().KEY_NAME) name: String?,
    @Field(Constant().KEY_CELL) cell: String?,
    @Field(Constant().KEY_PASSWORD) password: String?,
): Call<Contacts?>?
```

I am getting error on `Constant().KEY_NAME`, `Constant().KEY_CELL`, `Constant().KEY_PASSWORD`

> Error: An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant

Constant class.

```
class Constant {
  val BASE_URL = "http://istiak.ga/app/"

  val KEY_NAME = "name"
  val KEY_PASSWORD = "password"
  val KEY_CELL = "cell"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is convert your `Constants` class to an `object` like below

```
object Constants {
 const val BASE_URL = "http://istiak.ga/app/"

 const val KEY_NAME = "name"
 const val KEY_PASSWORD = "password"
 const val KEY_CELL = "cell"
}
```

Then you can directly reference each value instead of creating an instance of the `Constants` class for each variable you need as below

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("retrofit/POST/signup.php")
abstract fun signUp(
    @Field(Constant.KEY_NAME) name: String?,
    @Field(Constant.KEY_CELL) cell: String?,
    @Field(Constant.KEY_PASSWORD) password: String?,
): Call<Contacts?>?
```